# Installation of postgresql on linux mint 17.1 (problem with apt-get update)

Tags: apt, repository, postgresql

I have a linux mint system 17.1 and I want to install `postgresql`.

Now in trying to update the packages, I type: `sudo apt-get update` and here are the error messages I get:

```
W: Unable to recover archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/rebecca/partner/binary-am‌​d64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E: The download some index files failed, they have been ignored, or old were used instead.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Also, are you sure this is a problem? What happens if you try to run `sudo apt-get install postgresql`?

Answer (score 1):

The first error message you're seeing is just a warning: one of your configured repositories doesn't exist. The second error message should just be a warning too; the valid repositories in your setup have been updated despite the error.

So you should be able to install PostgreSQL:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

If you want to fix the warnings and errors you get when you run `apt-get update`, you should find the line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` or `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` which refers to `rebecca` `partner` and comment it by adding `#` at the start of the line.

Comment: I tried but the problem continues.

Comment: the release of linux mint 17.1 is rebecca. So I replaced the release in my sources.list and pgdg.list suite I commented the line that contains the prtner in sources.list before running sudo apt-get update but the problem continues.

Comment: Did you try installing the `postgresql` package?

Comment: yes, I installed the package but when I type the command: sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4 pgadmin3
I get this error message: Reading package lists ... Done
Shaft Construction dependencies
Reading state information ... Done
E: Could not find package postgresql-9.4
E: Could not find package matching the regular expression "postgresql-9.4"
E: Could not find package pgadmin3

Comment: OK, so you've got PostgreSQL installed, presumably version 9.6, which answers your original question. You don't need to install `postgresql-9.4` or `postgresql-9.6`, that's taken care of by `posgresql`. As for `pgadmin3`, you should ask a separate question and provide the contents of your various `sources.list` files.

Comment: The fact is that I want to install postgresql and here is the link I susi spirit to follow for installation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/898303/Installing-and-Configuring-PostgreSQL-on-Linux -Min

Comment: Now arriving at the command: apt-get update udo. I get this message: Ign http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg InRelease
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg Release.gpg
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg Release
Err http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg / main amd64 Packages
  404 Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]
Err http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg / main Packages i386
  404 Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg / main Translation-en_US

Comment: Ign http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg / Translation-en hand
Ign http://apt.postgresql.org rebecca-pgdg / main Translation-in
W: Unable to recover http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/rebecca-pgdg/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]

W: Unable to recover http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/rebecca-pgdg/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found [IP: 87.238.57.227 80]

E: The download some index files failed, they have been ignored, or old were used instead.

Comment: my sources.list file is empty.
Here are the contents of pgdg.lis file: deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ rebecca-hand pgdg

Comment: See the instructions in the page you linked to: "where I used “trusty” below, use the name of your release for Ubuntu, or the corresponding Ubuntu release if you you are using Linux Mint'. In your case, that's still "trusty", not "rebecca".

Comment: Hello Stephen Kitt !
I replaced "rebecca" with "trusty" but installing postgresql did not always work. I had to follow this installation guide http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/12/15/how-to-install-latest-postgresql-9-x-on-linux-mint-17-1-rebecca- lts-32-64bit-easy-guide / to do it and finally it took.
Thank you for your help.
and my apologies for absence.